# Snakemake Reports -- old styling and/or custom styling?

Tags: css, report, snakemake

I am trying to include a report of my Snakemake (7.18.2) workflow using the automated `snakemake --report` functionality. However, I find the styling of this report to be extremely clunky. e.g.: the linearized rules on the landing page, and the inclusion of all of the reported data in various sidebar menus/buttons. This is all a bit puzzling to me because previous versions of snakemake seemed to have much more readable automated reports.

For example:

- Snakemake 7.x.x styling (current, a bit hard to read):
  https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_downloads/b10d83889c3905e7b7557a62144a51ca/report.html#
- Snakemake 5.14.0 styling (old, easy to read):
  https://koesterlab.github.io/resources/report.html

I have searched through various snakemake repos and I don't think I am missing extra formatting code -- these both seem to have been generated with the vanilla `snakemake --report`.

Furthermore, the `custom.css` parameter [as described in the docs](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html#rendering-reports) does not seem to do anything with Snakemake 7.18.2.

---

**My question is:**

Is there any way to use the old styling for the `reports` or perhaps even better, a way to customize the layout? I am only vaguely familiar with the very broad basics of css and html, so I am not sure how I would begin to modify or inject my own styling here.

Comment: The style was actually massively changed in the following [pull request](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/pull/1470) that gave birth to release [7.2.0](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/releases/tag/v7.2.0). Given the number of changes I guess we cannot recover the old style by just using a custom stylesheet... I wish I could find a way to easily improve the way they look now. I also liked the old "table" style.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with you that this new style is clunky and hard to read. My work-around has been to create a custom report with R Markdown -- you could also use Jupyter and/or Quarto. Unfortunately it would take quite a lot of effort to manually recreate all the bells-and-whistles as the original Snakemake report, such as the tables with job properties.

As for the linear rulegraph, it appears that is a bug: https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/1938

Edit: just realized you commented on that issue thread, so you're already aware it's a bug. Leaving the link here for others.

Comment: I ended up learning some CSS and HTML basics along with templating via Python. Pretty frustrating since Snakemake previously had nice reports. R Markdown (or one of it's extensions) probably requires less boilerplate and looks pretty nice too -- thanks for the great idea :)